# How to get customer id from the given url in Jquery

Tags: jquery

How to get the customer_id from the given url in jquery.
http://example.com/admin/sales/index/store_id/51/customer_id/7570/key/1c5baa2e43516f28e03679c1bbff6b66590955d472db1aa2b46043d55ef1d314/

Comment: are you sure the url pattern will remain same all the time?

Comment: like just 4 digit id after customer id?

Comment: It may change...

Comment: can be any number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
window.location.pathname
```

Gives you the part of the url that is: "/admin/sales/index/store_id/51/customer_id/7570/key/..."

With this you can split it, and grab the element you want from the resulting array. (If the path pattern remains the same)

```
window.location.pathname.split("/")[7]
```

Another approach would be to regex it out, and that can be done like this:

```
window.location.pathname.match(/customer_id\/(\d+)\//)[1] // looks for digits after 'customer_id'
```

Comment: Great...
But we first may need to check wather customer_id is exist on url or not...
otherwise this may return a wrong value...

Comment: @Arslan well, thats not in your question, you wrote "from the given url" =)

Comment: But your regex approach will work with a small modification...

Comment: if( window.location.pathname.match(/customer_id\/(\d+)\//) != null){
 console.log(window.location.pathname.match(/customer_id\/(\d+)\//)[1]);
} 
thanks.. :)

Comment: rate this question too..

Answer (score 0):

Do not go with the hardcoded position of splitting array,

Use like the below is the safest way, another would be regex.

```js
let url = "http://example.com/admin/sales/index/store_id/51/customer_id/7570/key/1c5baa2e43516f28e03679c1bbff6b66590955d472db1aa2b46043d55ef1d314/";
   let splitURL = url.split("/");
console.log(url && splitURL[splitURL.indexOf("customer_id") + 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is [here](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/get-url-parameters-using-jquery.html)
function GetURLParameter(sParam)

{

```
var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);

var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');

for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)

{

    var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

    if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)

    {

        return sParameterName[1];

    }

}
```

}​

var tech = GetURLParameter('technology');
2
var blog = GetURLParameter('blog');